# Display a cube on a specific position in scene

Tags: augmented-reality

I'm tracking the position of an quadrangle on a surface with my camera. This works fine.
After getting these coordinates (4 edges) I want to display a cube on this position.
(AR-like).
How to calculate the model-transformations or (if it's better) to setup the camera-position ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: What language? What platform? There's not nearly enough information here.